# Does the implementation of Eigen depend on standard containers?

Tags: stl, eigen

Eigen is an awesome algebra/matrix computation c++ library and I'm using it in a developing project. But someone told me not to use it because it depends on standard containers, which is doubtful to me. The reason not to use standard containers is complicated and we just ignore it for now. My question is, does eigen's implementation really depends on the standard containers? I've searched on the Eigen homepage but nothing found. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather say **no** as there are only two very marginal use:

The first one is in `IncompleteCholesky` where `std::vector` and `std::list` are used to hold some temporary objects during the computation, not as member. This class is only used if a user explicitly uses it.

The second one is in `SuperLUSupport` module, which is a module to support a third library. Again, you cannot use accidentally!

The `StlSupport` module mentioned by Avi is just a helper module to ease the storage of Eigen's matrices within STL containers.

Comment: Thanks very much. We don't use IncompleteCholesky nor SuperLUSupport in the project. So you answer really helps me! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but a very little bit. You may not even need those parts, depending on your precise use. You can run a quick grep to see exactly what `std::` containers are used and where. In 3.3.0, there is a `std::vector` member as well as a `std::list<>::iterator` in `./src/IterativeLinearSolvers/IncompleteCholesky.h`, `std::vector`s are typically used as input for sparse matrices (`SparseMatrix::setFromTriplets`, although it really needs the iterators).

There is also the `./src/StlSupport/` directory, but I'm not sure that's what you don't want.

Comment: Yes, your conclusion is similar with @ggael . But you have taught me a useful skill: use `grep` to find specific class/library usage! Thanks!

Comment: @WenwenKang If ggael's answer best answered your question, please consider marking it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).